# Header Location PHP redirect's to wrong page

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I am using a php script to submit my form and send it to a specific email adress this all works fine.

But for my mobile version and my desktop version I use a different script because the Header Location redirect has a different output.

However when I click on my send button on my mobile version it still redirects me to the output of my dekstop version.

```
Desktop output = homepage.html
Mobile output = index.html
```

Any ideas?

Code in snippets

/* Desktop PHP */

```
<?php $Naam=$_POST['Naam'];
 $Email=$_POST['Email'];
 $Telefoon=$_POST['Telefoon'];
 $Bericht=$_POST['Bericht'];
 $to="info@pieterswebdesign.com";
 $subject="pieterswebdesign";
 $body="this is an automated message don't reply to this email \n\n $Naam,$Email,$Telefoon,$Bericht";
 mail($to,
$subject,
$body);
 header('Location: homepage.html');
 ?>
```

/*Mobile PHP */

```
<?php $Naam=$_POST['Naam'];
 $Email=$_POST['Email'];
 $Telefoon=$_POST['Telefoon'];
 $Particulier=$_POST['Particulier'];
 $Contacteermij=$_POST['Contacteermij'];
 $Bericht=$_POST['Bericht'];
 $to="info@pieterswebdesign.com";
 $subject="pieterswebdesign";
 $body="this is an automated message don't reply to this email \n\n $Naam,$Email,$Telefoon,$Particulier,$Contacteermij,$Bericht";
 mail($to,
$subject,
$body);
 header('Location: index.html');
 ?>
```

/* Desktop Form */

```
<div id="wrappercontactform">
  <div id="emptydivform"></div>
  <p id="formcontacthead">CONTACT FORM</p>

  <form id="contactform" class="form" action="send.php" method="POST">
    <p class="name">
      Naam
      <input type="text" name="Naam" id="name" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="email">
      E-mail adres
      <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="telefoonnummer">
      Telefoonnummer
      <input type="text" name="Telefoon" id="telefoonnummer" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="bericht">
      Bericht
      <textarea type="text" name="Bericht" id="bericht" placeholder="Typ hier..." /></textarea>
    </p>

    <button class="submit" input type="submit" form="contactform">Verstuur</button>


  </form>
```

/* Mobile form */

```
  <form id="contactform" class="form" action="sendmobile.php" method="POST">
    <p class="name">
      Naam
      <input type="text" name="Naam" id="name" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="email">
      E-mail adres
      <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="telefoonnummer">
      Telefoonnummer
      <input type="text" name="Telefoon" id="telefoonnummer" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="particulier">
      Particulier, zakelijk, vereniging...
      <input type="text" name="Particulier" id="particulier" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="contacteermij">
      Contacteer mij op (bv: datum & uur)
      <input type="text" name="contacteermij" id="contacteermij" placeholder="Typ hier..." />
    </p>

    <p class="bericht">
      Uw vraag / bericht
      <textarea type="text" name="Bericht" id="bericht" placeholder="Typ hier..." /></textarea>
    </p>

    <button class="submit" input type="submit" form="contactform">Verstuur</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: What determines whether the mobile or desktop code is loaded? Have you checked that this is working?

Comment: might be you are rendering same form for mobile and desktop ? because of form action it send form data to desktop version

Comment: I use media querie's for that so on index.html where mobile version should be redirected to these work perfectly you can check this at www.pieterswebdesign.com/desktop/index.html

Comment: How are you separating the PC & mobile form? As many suggest, it may just be using the PC one.

Comment: @MineshPatel I use 2 different actions one is action="send.php" for desktop the other is action="sendmobile.php" for mobile is this a problem?

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are being shown the "desktop" form on your mobile then, have you made sure that it's the right form being shown?

Comment: i would suggest go with @Caspar Wylie's answer

Comment: 100% sure since the input from the user is different on mobile and desktop :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are doing this is not suggested. You should have one page that is dynamic and shows the different designs on the front end. However, I suggest doing this (in your case)

```
<?php $Naam=$_POST['Naam'];
 $Email=$_POST['Email'];
 $Telefoon=$_POST['Telefoon'];
 $Particulier=$_POST['Particulier'];
 $Contacteermij=$_POST['Contacteermij'];
 $Bericht=$_POST['Bericht'];
 $to="info@pieterswebdesign.com";
 $subject="pieterswebdesign";
 $body="this is an automated message don't reply to this email \n\n $Naam,$Email,$Telefoon,$Particulier,$Contacteermij,$Bericht";
 mail($to,
$subject,
$body);

$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){

     header("Location: mobile.html");

}else{
     header("Location: desktop.html");

}
exit();

?>
```

It checks if the user is one a phone by using regex on the USER_AGENT string. This is how it is done in php. Doesn't look very nice though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and use exit(); after header location

Comment: ah yes. updating.

Comment: Ok i will give it a go :)! what exactly do you mean by dynamically having 2 different pages?  I have 1 contact.html file where I use media querie's to seperate the mobile version from the desktop version also why would the form submit twice the same if my action leads to a different PHP scripts on each form?

Comment: I mean on the front end you should have the same page - and then use css / javascript to change it's design if on mobile, etc. Sorry, didnt make that very clear. have updated.

Comment: It works so thx for that :), I just find it odd that when i ask a form to perform an action it doesn't do what is in the script of the action I asked the form to perform :p  This is getting to technical for a noob like me tbh :)

Comment: @CasparWylie well that is the case I have only one contact.html file and it is getting changed by media queries in css or do you meandthe page the header is redirecting towards should be the same?

Comment: So then why do you need to header to two different places??! It should be the same header if you are using the same page (please accept as answer if it worked).

Comment: Well I use a landing page on my desktop being index.html this page is not the one I want the people to be redirected towards when they submit a form. However on my mobile version I do want index.html to be the page they are getting redirected towards when they submit the form so I need two different locations where people are redirected towards when they submit the form accepted the answer btw thx :)

Comment: That is irrelevant . If you have a page that on the front end changes to work on different platforms, then just redirecting to that one page should be fine.